# why i get javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException? - setRollbackOnly

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa, apache-tomee

In my web applicaton I use OpenJPA on Apache Tomcat (TomEE)/7.0.37 server.

my entity User.class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Basic(optional = false)
  @Column(name = "id_user")
  private Integer idUser;
  @Size(max = 8)
  @Column(name = "login")
  private String login;
  @Size(max = 128)
  @Column(name = "password")
  private String password;
  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
  private Lecturer lecturer;
  @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
  private Student student;
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
  private List<UserHasRoles> userHasRolesList;

  //constructors, getters, setters
}
```

when i create new user:

```
    public void addUser(String log, String pass) {     
        User user = new User(); //utworzenie użytkownika i dodanie do bazy 
        user.setLogin(log);
        user.setPassword(pass);
        em.persist(user);
    }
```

i get exception:

```
javax.el.ELException: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction was rolled back, presumably because setRollbackOnly was called during a synchronization

Caused by:
org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.SetRollbackOnlyException - setRollbackOnly() called. See stacktrace for origin
at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl.setRollbackOnly(TransactionImpl.java:126)
```

I try to change generation id strategy, but it dosen't help.
What is wrong?

---

stack trace from my application:

```
org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareELException: javax.el.ELException: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction was rolled back, presumably because setRollbackOnly was called during a synchronization
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.invoke(ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.java:108)
at org.apache.myfaces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:68)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:120)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._broadcastAll(UIViewRoot.java:1028)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:286)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._process(UIViewRoot.java:1375)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:752)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationExecutor.execute(InvokeApplicationExecutor.java:38)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:170)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:117)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:197)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at filters.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:42)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:45)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

Caused by: javax.el.ELException: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction was rolled back, presumably because setRollbackOnly was called during a synchronization
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:291)
at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.invoke(ContextAwareTagMethodExpression.java:96)
... 30 more

Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Transaction was rolled back, presumably because setRollbackOnly was called during a synchronization
at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.convertException(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:345)
at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.invoke(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:283)
at model.logic.UserService$LocalBeanProxy.addUser(model/logic/UserService.java)
at model.backingbeans.RegisterBacking.register(RegisterBacking.java:91)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
... 32 more

Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: Unable to commit: transaction marked for rollback
at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:272)
at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionManagerImpl.commit(TransactionManagerImpl.java:252)
at org.apache.openejb.core.transaction.JtaTransactionPolicy.completeTransaction(JtaTransactionPolicy.java:328)
at org.apache.openejb.core.transaction.TxRequired.commit(TxRequired.java:75)
at org.apache.openejb.core.transaction.EjbTransactionUtil.afterInvoke(EjbTransactionUtil.java:76)
at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer._invoke(StatelessContainer.java:259)
at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer.invoke(StatelessContainer.java:191)
at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.synchronizedBusinessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:246)
at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.businessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:241)
at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler._invoke(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:83)
at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.invoke(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:279)
... 39 more

Caused by: org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.SetRollbackOnlyException: setRollbackOnly() called.  See stacktrace for origin
at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl.setRollbackOnly(TransactionImpl.java:126)
at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionManagerImpl.setRollbackOnly(TransactionManagerImpl.java:243)
at org.apache.openejb.core.TransactionSynchronizationRegistryWrapper.setRollbackOnly(TransactionSynchronizationRegistryWrapper.java:71)
at org.apache.openjpa.ee.RegistryManagedRuntime$TransactionManagerRegistryFacade.setRollbackOnly(RegistryManagedRuntime.java:128)
at org.apache.openjpa.ee.RegistryManagedRuntime.setRollbackOnly(RegistryManagedRuntime.java:74)
at org.apache.openjpa.ee.AutomaticManagedRuntime.setRollbackOnly(AutomaticManagedRuntime.java:274)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.setRollbackOnlyInternal(BrokerImpl.java:1660)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.setRollbackOnly(BrokerImpl.java:1640)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flush(BrokerImpl.java:1847)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.assignObjectId(StateManagerImpl.java:616)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.assignField(StateManagerImpl.java:703)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.beforeAccessField(StateManagerImpl.java:1615)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.accessingField(StateManagerImpl.java:1598)
at model.entity.User.pcGetidUser(User.java)
at model.entity.User.toString(User.java:137)
at java.text.MessageFormat.subformat(MessageFormat.java:1271)
at java.text.MessageFormat.format(MessageFormat.java:860)
at java.text.Format.format(Format.java:157)
at java.text.MessageFormat.format(MessageFormat.java:836)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.util.Localizer$Message.getMessage(Localizer.java:282)
at org.apache.openjpa.util.OpenJPAException.<init>(OpenJPAException.java:64)
at org.apache.openjpa.util.UserException.<init>(UserException.java:47)
at org.apache.openjpa.util.InvalidStateException.<init>(InvalidStateException.java:34)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.SingleFieldManager.preFlush(SingleFieldManager.java:567)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.SingleFieldManager.preFlush(SingleFieldManager.java:505)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.preFlush(StateManagerImpl.java:2982)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.PNewState.beforeFlush(PNewState.java:40)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.beforeFlush(StateManagerImpl.java:1054)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flush(BrokerImpl.java:2112)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flushSafe(BrokerImpl.java:2072)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.beforeCompletion(BrokerImpl.java:1990)
at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl.beforeCompletion(TransactionImpl.java:527)
at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl.beforeCompletion(TransactionImpl.java:512)
at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl.beforePrepare(TransactionImpl.java:413)
at org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:262)
... 49 more
```

Comment: Did you "see stacktrace for origin"?

Comment: Please include the entire stack trace, including all "Caused by" portions.  The last "Caused by" is the true source of your exception and is the thing that needs to be addressed.

Comment: how can i get last "Caused by" portion? I have only this above and "... 49 more"

Comment: @chrylis what does it mean "see stacktrace for origin"?

Comment: That is the entire stack trace; the "49 more" are above it. The setRollbackOnly method was called sometime between the time the transaction was opened and when it was committed. You need to find where and why.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ok, i find my fault:

I got this exception because I had password field in database for 64 character (CHAR(64)) and I tried to write there 128 character String. Changing table in database resolved my problem.

So, when you get this exception check if your @Entity class has same field (with same types) like your types in database table.

Thank you all for help.  I'm sorry for the trouble and confusion.